# Using jQuery.contains() method with data-attributes in this function instead of find()

Tags: jquery, contains, custom-data-attribute

How can I change this function to use the `jQuery.contains()` method instead of `find()`?

I'm using the function to filter clothing by various attributes (i.e. color, product-category, occasion, etc.), and the function currently only returns exact matches. Since items often have more than one value for an attribute (i.e. more than one color), I'd like to use `contains()` instead of `find()`, but I haven't been able to figure out the proper syntax to use `contains()` with data-attributes

I've posted a fiddle with a simple example of the function here: http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/WZpMh/5/

```
    $('#filterStyleOptions li a').click(function () {
        var attrStyle = $(this).data('style');
        $('#filterStyleOptions li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        if (attrStyle == 'All') {
            $('#content').find('li').show();
        } else {
            // $('#content').find('li').hide();
            $('#content').find('li:not([data-style="' + attrStyle + '"])').hide();
            $('#content').find('li[data-style="' + attrStyle + '"]').show();
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: use jquery filter() function

Comment: @TamilSelvan - I think that I can probably use *= here, but I'd love to know how to use filter() correctly because that would definitely come in handy :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have confused `jQuery.contains` for the contains *selector syntax*:

```
$('#content').find('li[data-style*="' + attrStyle + '"]').show();
```

The `*=` instead of `=` means contains. You can also use `~=` to look for only whole words, which is more likely to be what you want. The documentation for all this is here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: That's exactly what I needed :-D I'd forgotten that there were 2 different types of contains ;-) Thank you so much for not only explaining that to me, but for also telling me how to look for whole words - which will be very helpful :-D The system's making me wait 10 minutes until I can accept your answer, so unfortunately I can't accept it as quickly as you replied to my post ;-)